# How to sum value by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') limit 20, and sum remaining value if greater than 20?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

How to sum value by `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')` and id the first 20 rows of data, and sum the remaining value if greater than 20 else 0? supposed I have below data with below SQL, how to do it? thanks so much for any advice.

```
SELECT SUM(value), id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM test_table
GROUP BY id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
sum(value)  id  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
-------------------------------------------- 
64.98   123456  2021-01-01
64.98   123456  2021-01-02
64.98   123456  2021-01-03
64.98   123456  2021-01-04
64.98   123456  2021-01-05
64.98   123456  2021-01-06
72.34   123456  2021-01-07
64.98   123456  2021-01-08
64.98   123456  2021-01-09
103.80  123456  2021-01-10
64.98   123456  2021-01-11
64.98   123456  2021-01-12
64.98   123456  2021-01-13
64.98   123456  2021-01-14
64.98   123456  2021-01-15
64.98   123456  2021-01-16
64.98   123456  2021-01-17
64.98   123456  2021-01-18
64.98   123456  2021-01-19
64.98   123456  2021-01-20
64.98   123456  2021-01-21
64.98   123456  2021-01-22
64.98   123456  2021-01-23
64.98   123456  2021-01-24
144.98  123456  2021-01-25
64.98   123456  2021-01-26
64.98   123456  2021-01-27
64.98   123456  2021-01-28
64.98   123456  2021-01-29
64.98   123456  2021-01-30
64.98   123456  2021-01-31
64.98   123456  2021-02-01
64.98   123456  2021-02-02
64.98   123456  2021-02-03
64.98   123456  2021-02-04
720.92  123456  2021-02-05
66.98   123456  2021-02-06
66.98   123456  2021-02-07
66.98   123456  2021-02-08
64.98   123456  2021-02-09
64.98   123456  2021-02-10
64.98   123456  2021-02-11
64.98   123456  2021-02-12
64.98   123456  2021-02-13
64.98   123456  2021-02-14
64.98   123456  2021-02-15
64.98   123456  2021-02-16
64.98   123456  2021-02-17
64.98   123456  2021-02-18
64.98   123456  2021-02-19
64.98   123456  2021-02-20
64.98   223456  2021-01-20
54.98   223456  2021-01-21
```

...................................

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and edit the question with the needed info

Comment: The first 20 rows of data sort by `date`?

Comment: @FanoFN Yes, order by date desc

Comment: By date descending? Means the first 20 are the latest data? Can you update your question with the expected result out of the sample data you've provided? And check MySQL version by running `SELECT version();`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL version that supports window function then probably:

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn <= 20 THEN vals ELSE 0 END) AS 'SumOf1st20',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn > 20 THEN vals ELSE 0 END) AS 'SumOFOthers'
FROM
(SELECT SUM(value) AS vals, id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS dt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn
FROM test_table
GROUP BY id, dt) v
GROUP BY id;
```

But I wonder if this is exactly what you want since your sample data seems to be a result of your original query.

[Here's a sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db1ad714c2f328f435716a628db51e78) for reference.

This here is a way to replicate `ROW_NUMBER()` function in older MySQL version:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       CASE WHEN id=@idx THEN @rnk := @rnk+1 
        ELSE @rnk := 1 END AS rn,
        @idx := id
 FROM (SELECT id, 
          SUM(value) AS vals, DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y-%m-%d") AS dt 
   FROM test_table 
   GROUP BY id, dt)t1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0, @idx := NULL) r
 ORDER BY id, dt DESC
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=901f5849b56cad8642affb57a451ee25)

Although, (in rare occasions) I had experience where this doesn't perform as I expect it to be: the row numbering sometimes gets messed up.

With further testing, that "rare occasion" seems to be happening here. Since your original query include aggregation, I took that and compare it against the v8 compatible `ROW_NUMBER()` and I got different results. Upon observation, the row numbers were assigned before the `ORDER BY xxx DESC` occur. So, visually it does sort by `date` descending accordingly but the `rn` column *"incorrectly"* generated. The workaround I found was to perform the aggregation in subquery first then only attempt to generate the custom row numbering. See my updated query and fiddle above.

Comment: Hi, we changed the requirements, how to sum value by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') limit 20 day by day, and sum remaining value if greater than 20? if an id has 100 rows, and ,it will only show 21 rows, (limit 20 day by day and remaining value if greater than 20)

Comment: if you need, I will ask a new quesion

Comment: Hi, this is my new question, thanks so much for any advice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062900/how-to-sum-value-by-date-formatdate-y-m-d-the-limit-20-sumday-by-day-a

Comment: Hi, I can't use this SQL in MySQL version() 5.7.33, do you know the reason? Thanks so much for your advice.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL v 5.7 doesn't support window function (`ROW_NUMBER`). Let me see what I can do.

Comment:  Thanks so much for your reply!!!! I will try your SQL right now

Comment: @QueenElsa , I've made a few discovery while doing more testing. See my updated answer.